# Dynamically Adding Columns to DataFrame based on str.split() output

Tags: python, pandas, split

I currently have a dataframe with one column containing contact names such as:

```
Andrew Jones
James
Hugh Peter Michael
```

I am trying to split the names into mutiple columns so that I can separate first names from last names:

```
df[['Name Part One', 'Name Part Two', 'Name Part Three', 'Name Part Four']] = df['Contact Person'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
```

However this is giving the error:

> ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Which I believe must be related to the fact that for some Contact People, there are only 1 parts to the name, others 2, and so on.

How can I dynamically add columns depending on how many parts are split out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
names_df = df['Contact Person'].str.split(' ', expand=True)

column_mapping = {}
for i in range(names_df.shape[1]):
    column_mapping[i] = f'Name Part {i+1}'

names_df = names_df.rename(columns=column_mapping)

df = pd.concat([df, names_df], axis=1)
```